# ImageMagick compare without generating diff image

Tags: imagemagick, file-comparison

I'm using ImageMagick compare to calculate the difference between two images every five minutes on a Raspberry Pi. This takes almost a minute, and I suspect much of the CPU load is due to the generation of the difference image. All I need is the result, not the image. But if I don't supply the name of the result image, I get an error. Isn't this possible?

Answer (score 6):

I was struggling with the same issue right now and found the answer: **Yes!**

**TL; DR: You specify `NULL:` as the filename for the diff, i.e.**

```
compare -metric rmse foo.png bar.png NULL:
```

### ImageMagick's documentation

ImageMagick has support for specifying a number of different output formats. One of those are `x:` which opens a window for the user to immediately view the difference between the images.

You can read more about this in the [documentation of the `compare` program](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/#compare):

> Rather than saving the 'compare' image, you can of course view it directly, which I find more convenient, by output to the special "x:" output format, or using the "display" program. For example..
>
> `compare bag_frame1.gif bag_frame2.gif  x:`

Digging deeper into ImageMagicks documentation for image formats brought me
to [the list of "Image formats"](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) (look under the header "Pseudo-image Formats"), which specifies the `NULL` image format as

> Useful for creating blank tiles with montage (use NULL:). Also useful
> as an output format when evaluating image read performance.

### Performance boost

As a sidenote, I also compared the time for rendering to PNG, GIF, TGA, and `NULL:` 100 times to really verify that the NULL format is quicker. Note that I'm piping stderr (2) to /dev/null just to suppress terminal output from `compare`.

Outputting to a PNG (~0.085 seconds):

```
time for n in {1..100}; do compare -metric rmse foo.png bar.png out.png 2>/dev/null ; done

real    0m3,036s
user    0m7,582s
sys     0m0,911s
```

Outputting to a GIF (~0.147 seconds):

```
time for n in {1..100}; do compare -metric rmse foo.png bar.png out.gif 2>/dev/null ; done

real    0m8,951s
user    0m11,760s
sys     0m2,918s
```

Outputting to a TGA (~0.094 seconds):

```
$ time for n in {1..100}; do compare -metric rmse foo.png bar.png out.tga 2>/dev/null ; done

real    0m4,623s
user    0m8,466s
sys     0m0,981s
```

Outputting to `NULL:` (~0.067 seconds):

```
time for n in {1..100}; do compare -metric rmse foo.png bar.png NULL: 2>/dev/null ; done

real    0m1,967s
user    0m5,797s
sys     0m0,920s
```

### Conclusion

Outputting to `NULL:` is decisively faster than other output formats, though marginally faster than creating a PNG. This is probably because ImageMagick needs to create an internal diff image for the comparison regardless if it is written to a file or not, and the overhead for encoding it into a PNG file and writing it to disk seems to not be very demanding in my small test case.